# kafka kraft controller replacement

Tags: apache-kafka, raft, kraft

I want to replace controller for my kafka kraft cluster (without downtime if it possible). All my actions. All my actions lead to the fact that the cluster is not recoverable.

My actions:

1. change quorum from 3 to 2 on each brokers and controllers
2. restart 1 kafka broker... and the cluster in down.

My other tries - install new controller and change the quorum (replace the node), but this actions will broke the cluster.

Also, I try to find information in Internet, but I havent solution.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-631%3A+The+Quorum-based+Kafka+Controller
and
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-853:+KRaft+Voter+Changes

I haven't option `--add-voter`

`:/opt/kafka# ./bin/kafka-metadata-quorum.sh -h
usage: kafka-metadata-quorum [-h] --bootstrap-server BOOTSTRAP_SERVER [--command-config COMMAND_CONFIG] {describe} ...

This tool describes kraft metadata quorum status.

positional arguments:
{describe}
describe             Describe the metadata quorum info

optional arguments:
-h, --help             show this help message and exit
--bootstrap-server BOOTSTRAP_SERVER
A comma-separated list of host:port pairs to use for establishing the connection to the Kafka cluster.
--command-config COMMAND_CONFIG
Property file containing configs to be passed to Admin Client.`

Kafka Raft 3.4.0

Thank you.

All steps are in the post above.

Comment: Last I checked, there's no migration tool without downtime, yet, until Kafka 4.0 release, I thought. Notice this ticket is still open https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-14094

Comment: It's "grates" :( . Thank you for your answer.
I have solution with saving ID and bootstrap other node. But it not relevant for this issue.